# XBMC/Xbmcswift - Movie/TV-Show metadata

Tags: database, metadata, movie, xbmc

Is there a way for xbmcswift to automatically provide metadata for video items?

I know this is possible using a sqlite database, but is there a way to do this automatically without using a database/sqlite?

Possibly from websites like http://www.thetvdb.com/ and http://www.themoviedb.org/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: No.

xbmcswift is just a wrapper for the XBMC add-on api and the api doesn't provide a possibility to interact with scraper add-ons.

However, there is the "script.module.metahandler" add-on you could use (by requiring it via addon.xml) to retrieve data from thetvdb and themoviedb - but it slows down extremely your add-on.